# Javascript : show load image gif and freeze webpage until xmlhttpRequest responce is received

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, loading

I want to show a loading gif until I get a response back from the server after pushing **get score** button. I am using flask and used following code to get and post the request. I also want to freeze the webpage until the response is displayed in the result field.

JavaScript Code:

```
function pushDatatoServer(){
    baseURL = 'localhost'
    port = app_port
    endpoint = '/push'
    url = 'http://'+baseURL+':'+port+endpoint
    console.log(url)
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhttp.open("POST",url , true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("secretKey", "xSecretx");
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200){
            var res = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            console.log(res)
            document.getElementById("final_result").innerHTML = res['riskScore'];
            //var maxval = 100;
            //var minval = 0;
            //var moreisgood = false;
            //var col = rgbify(maxval, minval, val, moreisgood)
            var score = res['riskScore'];
            if(score >= 0 && score <= 30 ){
                    var val = rgb(152,209,84);
                }
                else if (score >= 30 && score <=70){

                    var val =  rgb(253,179,74);
                }
                else  {
                    var val = rgb(255,107,107);
                }

            $("#final_result").css("background-color", val);
        }
    }
    console.log(currentState)
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(currentState));
 }
```

HTML button code:

```
 <div class="endspan1"  align="right">
     <input type="button" class=" button1" value="Get Score" onclick="pushDatatoServer()"  id="pushDatatoServer">      
 </div>
```

Result Field HTML code:

```
 <span  type="text" class="resultField"  id="final_result" readonly ></span
```

Comment: display your gif just before `xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(currentState));` ... hide your gif after `$("#final_result").css("background-color", val);`

Comment: `freeze the webpage` ... use a synchronous XMLHttpRequest :p (just kidding) - what do you mean "freeze"?

Comment: I just want to block user from using web page until I get the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to somehow prevent user from any interactions till request finish you can block the whole page with invisible div.

Basically you spawn invisible element with higher z-index and transparent background. When you want to enable you page again you just hide the block element.

```js
function blockPage() {
  $("#block-element").show();
  alert("i was blocked and i cant be clicked again");
}

function unblockPage() {
  $("#block-element").hide();
}
```

```css
#block-element {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999999;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="blockPage()">block me</button>

<div id="block-element">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with `pointer-events: none; overflow: hidden;`on your body or overlay an transparent div with full viewport size.
But catch and handle errors (bad request, timeout....whatever) otherwise your website won’t work anymore.

This is a very big intrusion to the users experience!